# 3D Maze OpenGL Implementation

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I'm trying to create a simple 3D Maze in opengl. My initial idea was to have a grid of cubes with some of the faces of each cube transparent (for the corridors). However, I'm having a little trouble thinking of a way to do this efficiently. I don't want to have to define every single cube separately for my maze, that would be a huge mess of code (I think).

Also, would I need to create new cubes each time, or could I define a single cube and simply translate it while redrawing it to form the maze?

Comment: If you want to go with the cube idea. Fill the entire grid with cubes, then use a maze generation algorithm such as depth first search ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm ) to move through the grid, removing cubes that are no longer part of the maze. Code should be simple for initializing the cubes. Just fill every grid spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining each cube separetly would create a huge mess of code, as you said. Also it would be impossible to implement randomly generated mazes. And it would be very tiring to do any changes on the maze.

I would go with the "defining a single cube and simply translating it". Define a function which renders a cube with its center at the origin, and translate it according to its world coordinates.

I don't think you should use transparency at all. Simply render a cube if there is one and don't if there isn't one.

```
for(i=0; i<width; i++){
    for(j=0; j<height; j++){
        if(maze[i][j] == 1){  // Means there is a cube there
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j * scale, 0, i * scale);
            DrawCube();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose you could use a similar structure for collision detection too.